# Fill N-leaf tree from File

Tags: java, performance

I've built an N-leaf tree with a pre-defined max level.

The data that I'm filling in is about 150million characters.

The way I'm filling the tree is by creating a `list<Character>` of length equal to the max level, then calling an `addNodes(List<Character>)` method.(Source code will be below)

Now the problem is that the higher the max level is, the longer it takes, which is obvious. With `level = 6` it takes about 4 minutes, whereas with `level = 7` it takes way over 20 minutes.

What I am looking for is a way to possibly fill the tree in parallel(which I don't know how to do or if it would even benefit at all) or make the filling process more efficient, memory is not the issue(atleast currently).

Source code:

Node:

```
public class Node {
    Node parent;
    List<Node> children;
    Character keyvalue;
    int count;

    //Constructors & getter and setter methods
    }
```

Tree:

```
public class Tree{
    Node root

    public void addListToTree(List<Character> list){
        //check if list.isEmpty
        if(root.children.isEmpty()){
            Node parent = root;

            for (Character e : list) {
                Node node = new Node(parent, e, 1, 0);
                parent.addChildren(node);
                parent = node;
            }
        } else {
            Node tmp = root;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Node node = new Node(null, list.get(i), 1, 0);

                if (-1 != tmp.getChildIndex(node)) {
                    tmp = tmp.getChild(node);
                    tmp.setCount(1); //increments counter by 1
                } else {
                    node.setParent(tmp);
                    tmp.addChildren(node);
                    tmp = node;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ReadFileContents:

```
public void start() {

    String file_contents = "";
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(filepath));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            file_contents += tmp;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Character> tmp = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char e : file_contents.toCharArray()) {
        tmp.add(e);
        // System.out.println("Chunksize: " + chunksize);
        if (chunksize == tmp.size()) {
            toTrain.addListToTree(tmp);
            tmp.remove(0);
        }
    }
    while (tmp.size() > 0) {
        toTrain.addListToTree(tmp);
        tmp.remove(0);
    }
}
```